# On Execution of vscode.executeInlayHintProvider comamnd, hints are not getting added/shown in the document (vscode version 1.82.2)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

On Execution of vscode.executeInlayHintProvider comamnd, hints are not getting added/shown in the document. Please note, hints are getting added/shown, when we type any character in the editor.I need to execute vscode.executeInlayHintProvider built-in command, on some context menu in the editor.
I am facing two issues on executing vscode.executeInlayHintProvider comamnd:-

1.hints are not getting added/shown in the editor even though my custom hint provider (HintsProvider, as shwon below) which implements vscode.InlayHintsProvider  is getting called.
2.my custom hint provider (HintsProvider, as shwon below) is getting called on
typing in the document. I want this is to be invoked only on execution of command - vscode.executeInlayHintProvider.

```
export class HintsProvider implements vscode.InlayHintsProvider {
    onDidChangeInlayHints?: vscode.Event<void>;
    static counter: number = 90;
    provideInlayHints(document: vscode.TextDocument, range: vscode.Range, token: vscode.CancellationToken): vscode.ProviderResult<vscode.InlayHint[]> {
        var provider = new HintsProvider();
        return new Promise<vscode.InlayHint[]> ((resolve,reject) =>{
        let ret: Array<vscode.InlayHint> = new Array();
        HintsProvider.counter++;
        let tempList: Array<vscode.InlayHintLabelPart> = new Array();
        let temp: vscode.InlayHintLabelPart = new vscode.InlayHintLabelPart(`labelHint${HintsProvider.counter}`);
        temp.tooltip = "hint tooltip";
        tempList.push(temp);
        let start = range && range.start ? range.start : new vscode.Position(1, 0);
        let retValue: vscode.InlayHint = new vscode.InlayHint(start, tempList, vscode.InlayHintKind.Parameter);
        let textRange = (range && range.start && range.end) ? range : new vscode.Range(new vscode.Position(1, 1), new vscode.Position(5, 10));
        let edit: vscode.TextEdit = new vscode.TextEdit(textRange, "hint text to be inserted");
        retValue.textEdits = new Array();
        retValue.textEdits.push(edit);
        ret.push(retValue);        
        resolve(ret);            
        });        
    }

    resolveInlayHint?(hint: vscode.InlayHint, token: vscode.CancellationToken): vscode.ProviderResult<vscode.InlayHint> {
        return new Promise<vscode.InlayHint>((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(hint);
        })
    }

  private onGeneratEvent = async (event:GenerateNLtoSQLErrorEventParams):Promise<any> =>{
      var pos = new vscode.Position(10, 0);
      var endPos = new vscode.Position(12, 0);
      let range:vscode.Range = new vscode.Range(pos,endPos);
      vscode.window.showErrorMessage(event.message);
        return vscode.commands.executeCommand("vscode.executeInlayHintProvider",vscode.Uri.parse(event.ownerUri),range).then ( (temp1) =>{
          let ret = new Array();          
          let list = new Array();          
          let hintLabelPart = new vscode.InlayHintLabelPart(`hint1`);
          hintLabelPart.tooltip = "hint tooltip";
          list.push(hintLabelPart);
          let inlayHint = new vscode.InlayHint(new vscode.Position(1, 0), list, vscode.InlayHintKind.Parameter);
          let edit = new vscode.TextEdit(new vscode.Range(new vscode.Position(1, 1), new vscode.Position(5, 10)), "textTobeInserted");
          inlayHint.textEdits = new Array();
          inlayHint.textEdits.push(edit);
          return inlayHint;
        });
  }
```